# Which map projection maps y=m1*lat+b1, x=m2*long+b2?

Tags: svg, kml, google-earth

I'm looking for a map of the US in this simple format. Then I can calibrate the simple mapping and do a report for our business by making a dynamic SVG file that places markers on that map.

Right now we are using Google Earth and a dynamically generated KML file, but the Google Earth imagery is too complex and the projection is wrong.

Comment: In what form is the map needed?  An image, a vector dataset like a shapefile, something else?  Or do you just need to know the name of this projection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Corrected Answer (based on comment by whuber)**

whuber has said the correct answer should be **Plate Carree**

---

**Original Wrong Answer:**

I think you want [Mercator projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection), from the [Normal/Transverse Mercator comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_Mercator_projection#General_features_of_the_spherical_transverse_Mercator), the normal projection has the following properties:

- The central meridian projects to the straight line x = 0. Other meridians project to straight lines with x constant.
- The equator projects to the straight line y = 0 and parallel circles project to straight lines of constant y.
- Projected meridians and parallels intersect at right angles.

You may want to ask this on [GIS - Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Because this answer has been accepted, I feel obliged to point out that it is incorrect and have downvoted it to make other readers aware of that.  The bulleted items describe cylindrical projections, of which the Plate Carree and Mercator are two (dramatically different) examples.  The former is what the question refers to.

Comment: @whuber I have changed my answer to point out I was wrong, thanks for spotting my error!

Comment: Downvote removed.